# Django emptying display value after submitting form

Tags: django, django-forms

I want my fields to show no value after submitting my django form, but I can't seem to find a way on how to do this. I think I just need to add something to my html, but just can't find out what exactly. Below is my html.

```
            <form method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
                <div>{{ form.ervaring|as_crispy_field }}</div>
                <div class="form-row">
                    <div class="form-group col-md">{{ form.startjaar|as_crispy_field }}</div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md">{{ form.eindjaar|as_crispy_field }}</div>
                </div>
                <div>{{ form.functie|as_crispy_field }}</div>
                <div>{{ form.beschrijving|as_crispy_field }}</div>
                <div>
                    <a class="btn btn-primary" href="{% url 'my_cv' %}">Done</a>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Add</button>
                </div>
            </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you need to do anything here( in the template code ). Look into the form request handler code. If in the response you are sending the same form object, that came from the request, then it would be prefilled with the same values.
This type of response helps when a user enters some incorrect values.

I assume, in your case, the user is successfully submitting the form, so I would suggest, a simple solution to redirect the user to the form page.
Or else, overwrite the form object in the response with a new form object.

Comment: Yes this was exactly what I needed to do. I put a check to see if the form was valid and then redirected it to the page url. Thanks a lot!